# The hidden truth

Tags: riddle

I am the winter, the summer, the spring.
I am everywhere, yet you cannot see me.
I am the one who knocks at your door.
I am the one who falls below.
I am the one you never wish existed.
I am death, the final unknown.
I am all of these in one, what am i?

Comment: Clearly the answer is Walter White, because he is the one that knocks

Comment: **Amazing** answer, but incorrect, sorry.

Comment: This riddle is very deep, and philosophical. It isn't going to be something funny.

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation. You don't mention being Fall, but you are the "one who falls below." I'm not sure what to do with that.

Comment: That isn't it, it isn't a season. :P

Comment: A hint when composing riddles:  A good riddle usually has some kind of play on words or alternate meaning, so that you have to interpret part of the riddle in a non-obvious way in order to solve it.  It is also unambiguous; when you have the solution, it should be obvious that the solution is correct.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain It looks to me as though this riddle has plenty of wordplay and alternate meanings (1: whatever the answer is, it can't be winter *and* summer *and* spring; 3: it probably doesn't literally knock at a door; 4 & 6 are probably also metaphorical clues). It's also hard to tell whether the solution will be obviously correct until it's solved; none of the current answers are very convincing, and none of them are accepted either. I find it utterly bizarre that this interesting-looking riddle has so many downvotes.

Comment: Perhaps nobody correctly answered because they were all reading “you never wish existed” as ‘you wish never existed’.  Eh?  Well, I will answer it as written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Pace of life

I am the winter, the summer, the spring.

> Pace of life includes all of seasons.

I am everywhere, yet you cannot see me.

> We never notice that life is passing.

I am the one who knocks at your door.

> We face some chances in our life.

I am the one who falls below.

> Some days of life are terrible.

I am the who the one you never wish existed.

> We want to be young for ever.

I am death, the final unknown.

> Death is a part of our life. We never can predict that.

Comment: honestly. i would have to go with this answer if anything

Answer (score 3):

I think it is

> Time

I am the winter, the summer, the spring.

> Time starts the seasons, time makes the order.

I am everywhere, yet you cannot see me.

> Time is everywhere, but you can't see time.

I am the one who knocks at your door.

> Time tells you a lot of information. (Knocks at your door)

I am the one who falls below.

> Time falls below when you are late.

I am the who the one you never wish existed.

> People want to be young forever.

I am death, the final unknown.

> Eventually, you die. You die when time passes.

I am all of these in one, what am i?

> Time

Comment: what all do you know in Java?!

Comment: Nothing anymore. Should probably update my bio. 

Answer (score 2):

> Love?
>
> Song titles/lyrics:
>
> Love is the winter, Love is summer, Love is spring,
>
> Love is everywhere,
>
> Love comes knocking,
>
> Love falls down,
>
> I wish love never existed,
>
> Love is Death
>
> Then again I bet Time, The Past, or any other number of things could go here with the same justification.  Is there a best fit answer? :(

Answer (score 0):

I am the winter, the summer, the spring.
I am everywhere, yet you cannot see me.
I am the one who knocks at your door.
I am the one who falls below.
I am the who the one you never wish existed.
I am death, the final unknown.
I am all of these in one, what am i?

> We can have an answer to this with different words but inner essence being one! So I would say it's mainly EGO that gives rise to I and also takes birth and so has death. At times though we know what we are doing is wrong we still do it and it's plainly cause of EGO making one play to its tricks! It's present everywhere in every one it helps you to knock the door of opportunity and it still has ways to be intangible! So LIFE or PRANA can also be related highly to this question!! Interesting riddle very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

I am the winter, the summer, the spring.

> You could see this as describing some characteristic which is mutual among the seasons so named.
>  If, however, it is describing something which changes form so as to become each season, then it would seem obvious that Time is that thing.
>  However, Time is merely the platform on which the calendar plays.  It is a property of the Earth which varies to produce the seasonal changes.

I am everywhere, yet you cannot see me.

> There are many things which are both ubiquitous and not visible:  air; moisture in the air — although that can be visible when colloidal; non-visible electromagnetic fluxes.
>  There are also things which are considered to be intangible.  Is that, however, what is meant by “cannot see me”?  If Happiness is an intangible state of mind, does that mean that you could say that we cannot see it?  We can see expressions of it.
>  Also, of special note, this means that it can't be something which is ever visible by anyone — leastways not by those of whom the riddler is aware.

I am the one who knocks at your door.

> This can be taken quite figuratively, so to speak.  Indeed, that does seem most likely, given the mood carried by the other pieces of the riddle and the fact that, if it were describing a household door, then we'd be limited to many rather small possible players for our solution.
>  Seemingly it couldn't be something great and metaphysical, unless we were considering avatars or the like.

I am the one who falls below.

> This is quite broad.  We know it describes something which is capable of existing in a state that can be described with some comparison to a vertical nature, and that it has a delineation which marks a region considered to be ‘below’.
>  It also tells us that the usual state of the thing is to be above that region.
>  Dewpoints, freezing points, and other such thermodynamic measurements come to mind.

I am the one you never wish existed.

> Well, if we never wish it existed, then it must be something which we take for a granted object.  We never experience its absence, nor indeed feel deprived if such absence were to occur.
>  So, therefore, we never wish that it existed.

I am death, the final unknown.

> The cessation of life?  Well, perhaps.
>  The thing which makes death unknown to us now is that nobody ever talks about it — well, not often; when they do, many don't believe it.  Why?
>  Certain people tend to regard that there is a state of being somehow separated from our living consciousness, and that any descriptions pertaining thereof can be explained as variations of the consciousness with which they are familiar.

I am all of these in one, what am i?

> Well, okay;
>  it seemed like it would be more metaphysical, like **Thought** or **Mind**, but the relation between those and some of the clues are rather esoteric.  Too much so, perhaps?
>  I considered things like **Electron** or **Motion**, but they also fit only a few of the clues.

---

It seems that it needs be

> ***Life***

I am the winter, the summer, the spring.

> the seasons may be caused by the inclination of the Earth's rotation, but it is Life which operates the climate.

I am everywhere, yet you cannot see me.

> many things which live surround us, but Life itself is unseen.

I am the one who knocks at your door.

> living energy produces the act of knocking.

I am the one who falls below.

> falling ill, seemingly.

I am the one you never wish existed.

> you may think there are many times when we wish something were alive rather than dead.
>  How often do we notice ourselves wishing that Life existed?

I am death, the final unknown.

> Life allows for Death of itself?

---

Okay, so it seems that the conclusion isn't all too good.  But, I was loath to not publish my examinations of the clues.